# Should I include documents (letters of recommendation and SOP) that is not required for PhD admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I am applying for a PhD position.

The interesting thing is that the department does not require an SOP and letters of recommendation. There is no place I can upload my SOP, and they are very clear that letters of recommendation are not required, for there is a place where I can upload the letters.

The problem is, I have never asked my professors for an open recommendation letter. I think it is quite weird to ask them to send the letter to me so that I can upload on the system. It is always that I give their emails and the system automatically sends the request and they themselves upload their letters.

**My question is, should I ask my professors for a letter of recommendation and upload it to the system?**

Comment: If they don't require this, why do you think it would be helpful?